# Where am I going wrong with my bounding box function?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, octree

I am writing a bounding box module for the [octree](https://github.com/BioHaskell/octree/tree/master) library. You can find my branch [here](https://github.com/mlitchard/octree/tree/MBB). In the function below, I try to make explicit the implicit bounding boxes of an `Octree`. The problem is, not all bounding boxes are valid.

This is the function in question, followed by a way to replicate the problem in `ghci`.

```
explicateMBB :: (BBox3, Octree a) -> [BBox3]
explicateMBB (mbb, (Leaf _)) = [mbb]
explicateMBB (mbb, (Node { split = split',
                           nwu   = nwu',
                           nwd   = nwd',
                           neu   = neu',
                           ned   = ned',
                           swu   = swu',
                           swd   = swd',
                           seu   = seu',
                           sed   = sed'
             })) =
   mbb:concatMap explicateMBB octList 
  where 
    octList = zip boxList children
    boxList = [swdBox, sedBox, nwdBox, nedBox, swuBox, seuBox, nwuBox, neuBox]
    children = [swd',sed',nwd',ned',swu',seu',nwu',neu']
    swdBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (minX mbb) (minY mbb) (minZ mbb)
        neuCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (v3y split') (v3z split')
    sedBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (minY mbb) (minZ mbb)
        neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (v3y split') (minZ mbb)
    nwdBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (minX mbb) (v3y split') (minZ mbb)
        neuCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (maxY mbb) (v3z split')
    nedBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (v3y split') (minZ mbb)    
        neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (maxY mbb) (v3z split')
    swuBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (minX mbb) (minY mbb) (v3z split')
        neuCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (v3y split') (maxZ mbb)
    seuBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (minY mbb) (v3z split')
        neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (v3y split') (maxZ mbb)
    nwuBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner 
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (minX mbb) (v3y split') (v3z split')
        neuCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (maxY mbb) (maxZ mbb)
    neuBox = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner
      where
        swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (v3y split') (v3z split')
        neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (maxY mbb) (maxZ mbb)
```

To replicate problem:

`git clone https://github.com/mlitchard/octree.git`

`git checkout MBB`

`stack ghci`

In `ghci`, do the following :

```
:m + Data.List Data.Vector.Class System.Random System.Random.Shuffle Data.BoundingBox.B3
let infinity = (read "Infinity") :: Double
let swdCorner = Vector3 (-infinity) (-infinity) (-infinity)
let neuCorner = Vector3 (infinity) (infinity) (infinity)
let rbb = bound_corners swdCorner neuCorner
xGen <- getStdGen
yGen <- newStdGen
zGen <- newStdGen
let xPoints = shuffle' [-256 .. 256] 513 xGen
let yPoints = shuffle' [-256 .. 256] 513 yGen
let zPoints = shuffle' [-256 .. 256] 513 zGen
let xPoints' = map fromInteger xPoints :: [Double]
let yPoints' = map fromInteger yPoints :: [Double]
let zPoints' = map fromInteger zPoints :: [Double]
let tup513 = zip3 xPoints' yPoints' zPoints'
let construct_vect = (\(x,y,z) -> Vector3 x y z)
let vect513 = map construct_vect tup513
let pre_oct513 = zip vect513 [1 .. 513]
let octree513 = fromList pre_oct513
length $ filter (== False) $ map isValidMBB $ explicateMBB (rbb,octree513)
```

The answer will be 9, but should be 0.

I feel like one of the `fooBox` `where` clauses is wrong, but I have gone over each one several times, and I am not seeing which one it is.

If you needed a visual aid like I did, I found [this pic](https://geidav.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/full_octree.png?w=820) to be helpful. My sample does 2 subdivisions.

Any insight into what is going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Just saying: this kind of issue could much nicer be presented [with a Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell).

Comment: @leftaroundabout can you use jupyter on stackoverflow?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: that would be way awesome! But no, actually I thought of linking a notebook from Github, but of course external links are in principle not that great. Hm, [I suppose I just ask for such a feature on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326619/would-it-be-feasible-to-implement-some-kind-of-integration-for-jupyter-notebooks)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your second `where` clause:

```
where
    swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (minY mbb) (minZ mbb)
    neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (v3y split') (minZ mbb)
```

should be:

```
where
    swdCorner = Vector3 (v3x split') (minY mbb) (minZ mbb)
    neuCorner = Vector3 (maxX mbb) (v3y split') (v3z split') <-- v3z split'
```